# How to create a link in OneNote that opens inside Teams' frame?

Tags: url, hyperlink

If I enter a Microsoft Team, then go to the Notebook, and create a page using OneNote, I can create a Web link to an external page. When I click the link, it opens it in a new tab or window. How can I get it to open, but still within the frame of Teams, so users can still see the channels links to the right and the tabs along the top?